# Can I use Gregorio with ConTeXt?

Tags: context, gregorio

I've been typesetting documents in LaTeX using [Gregorio](http://gregorio-project.github.io/index.html) to set Gregorian chant notation. Now I'm trying out ConTeXt, and want to use it with Gregorio. I think this should be possible, because Gregorio is built on plain TeX. I have TeX Live, which includes the gregoriotex package for LaTeX, but there's nowhere that I can find where it's packaged as a module usable from ConTeXt.

From reading the [Modules](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules) page on the wiki, I think I might need to repackage Gregorio as a ConTeXt module myself—but it's not clear how to do that or how much work it will be. Is it possible to use Gregorio from ConTeXt, and if so, how?